# Intersection of Two Lists of Tuples in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to find the intersection of two lists in Prolog using the `intersection()` function. Unfortunately, my code is giving undesirable results.

Here is what I have:

```
RESULTA = [ ('10:00 am - 11:15 am', 'TR'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'T'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'M')].

RESULTB = [ ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('3:00 pm - 3:50 pm', 'TR')].

intersection(RESULTA, RESULTB, AB).
```

The desired output is `('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R')` however, the code returns `RESULTA = AB, AB = [].`

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

RESULTA and RESULTB are actually generated from bagof() operations. My actual code is:

```
1 ?- bagof((TIME, DAYS), COURSE^teaches_at('Dr. J. Leidig', COURSE, TIME, DAYS), RESULTA).
RESULTA = [ ('10:00 am - 11:15 am', 'TR'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'T'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'M')].

2 ?- bagof((TIME, DAYS), COURSE^teaches_at('Dr. El-Said', COURSE, TIME, DAYS), RESULTB).
RESULTB = [ ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('3:00 pm - 3:50 pm', 'TR')
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is really queries to Prolog.

There are 3 different queries: each query ends with a period. All three queries are completely independent, even if they share variables with same names.

To do what you want just change periods to commas:

```
RESULTA = [ ('10:00 am - 11:15 am', 'TR'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'T'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'M')],
RESULTB = [ ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('3:00 pm - 3:50 pm', 'TR')],
intersection(RESULTA, RESULTB, AB).
```

Update after the question updated:

```
bagof((TIME, DAYS), COURSE^teaches_at('Dr. J. Leidig', COURSE, TIME, DAYS), RESULTA),
bagof((TIME, DAYS), COURSE^teaches_at('Dr. El-Said', COURSE, TIME, DAYS), RESULTB),
intersection(RESULTA, RESULTB, AB).
```

Comment: In the actual code, RESULTA and RESULTB are both lists generated from separate bagof() operations so it is not possible for me to declare the lists as you have above. I will add the original code to my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AdamJakiela - it's completely the same. Just use commas instead of periods. See my answer updated. But it's better to define a helper predicate to not type such long queries all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you must use that variables in a rule, like

```
test(AB) :-
    RESULTA = [ ('10:00 am - 11:15 am', 'TR'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'T'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'M')],
    RESULTB = [ ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R'), ('3:00 pm - 3:50 pm', 'TR')],
    intersection(RESULTA, RESULTB, AB).
```

then consult the file. The you'll get

```
?- test(AB).
AB = [ ('6:00 pm - 8:50 pm', 'R')].
```

Comment: Since the lists are generated dynamically with bagof() operations (see post edit) I am not able to declare the lists within the rule. Instead I tried declaring 'test(AB) :- intersection(RESULTA, RESULTB, AB).' but this also returned an empty list.